# Module parse failed: Unexpected token (214:33) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. TypeScript CRA project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs, create-react-app

I've had a Typescript react project I've been working on for the past couple of months. Everything worked fine until yesterday when I run `npm audit fix` and `npm audit fix --force` to fix some security errors I honestly did not understand where or what caused them.

That broke my application and after running `npm install` and `npm clean-install` I am getting this error

```
./src/Components/SearchForm.tsx 214:33
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (214:33)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     className: "w-[25%] bg-gray-100 border py-2 px-4 rounded-lg cursor-pointer",
|     onClick: function onClick() {
>       departureDateInput.current?.focus();
|     },
|     __self: _this,
```

After some research, I found an answer that I should remove the `?` in my Typescript projects.
For example this line `departureDateInput.current?.focus();` should be `departureDateInput.current.focus();`

While this works my project is quite huge and I honestly don't want to find all of them and fix them manually.

An answer on a similar question on stack overflow claimed i need to make some settings on `webpack`and or `babel`. I have never worked with babel or webpack explicitly on my own so i dont even know how to start on that.

I dont know if this helps but here is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Never force an audit fix unless you know what you're doing. Rollback your changes or try to update your version of CRA.

Comment: @Arkellys if I dont force an audit fix how do I fix those security problems

Comment: You update the libraries from which the problems come from. If there is no update available, you can wait for it. If you decide to force the fixes, you need to check all the breaking changes and update your code accordingly so it doesn't break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, updating create-react-app fixed my problem

```
npm install react-scripts@latest
```